# Exclude list of files/folder from backup

Tags: windows, batch-file

I use XCOPY to backup disks from one disk to another. The only thing I have is an extensive list of files and folders to exclude.

The following XCOPY command works correctly:

`XCOPY Z:\*.* "C:\Backup" /D /E /I /H /C /Y /EXCLUDE:exclude_z.txt`

I have problems with long paths, when it has 254 characters it fails.

I've looked at the option of doing it with ROCOCOPY but it won't let me add an exclusions file, it only has XF and XD, but it's a very long list.